Conjugate prior for a beta distribution
What is the conjugate prior of the beta distribution? All I can find is the wikipedia page on conjugate prior. Is this correct? And does anyone know where it came from? Like a specific paper? Thanks

Wikipedia's suggestion of $\propto \left(\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha),\Gamma(\beta)}\right)^k , p^\alpha , q^\beta$ updating $p$ to $p \prod\limits_{i=1}^n x_i$ and $q$ to $q \prod\limits_{i=1}^n (1-x_i)$  and $k$ to $k + n$ seems obviously reasonable given the beta likelihood $\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha),\Gamma(\beta)} x_i^\alpha (1-x_i)^\beta$.  Finding the constant of proportionality may not be easy.

@Thomas You can check the correctness of the stated kernel from the definition of conjugacy by direct algebraic calculation. Nothing mysterious is involved. Don't expect papers to show results that would be set as undergrad homework.  As Henry suggests,  obtaining a closed form expression for the normalising constant may be difficult, if possible at all. This might not necessarily be a big problem in practice.
